# Aurelia Validation - no message shown on failed validation

Tags: validation, aurelia

I've been working through the Aurelia-Validation example, and I have the following:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="styles/styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.js**

```js
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class Welcome{
  static inject() { return [Validation]; }
  constructor(validation) {
    this.heading = 'Welcome to the Aurelia Navigation App!';
    this.firstName = 'John';
    this.lastName = 'Doe';

this.validation = validation.on(this)
    .ensure('firstName')
    .isNotEmpty()
    .hasMinLength(3)
    .hasMaxLength(10)
.ensure('lastName')
    .isNotEmpty()
    .hasMinLength(3)
    .hasMaxLength(10);
  }

  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }  

  welcome() {
    this.validation.validate()//validate will fulfill when validation is valid and reject if not
        .then(  () => {
            alert(`Welcome, ${this.fullName}!`);
    })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("validation error");
        });
  }
 }
```

**welcome.html**

```
<template>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<require from="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"></require>
<section style="padding-top:2%;">
    <h2 class="text-center">${heading}</h2>
    <form role="form" submit.delegate="welcome()" validate.bind="validation"class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <p style="help-block aurelia-validation-message"></p>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="firstName" type="text" value.bind="firstName" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="lastName" type="text" value.bind="lastName" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Full Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <p>${fullName}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="half-rule">
</form> 
</section>
</template>
```

**main.js**

```
import{ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy} from 'aurelia-validation';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging()
    .plugin('aurelia-validation', (config) =>
{config.useViewStrategy(ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy.TWBootstrapAppendToInput);}); //Add this line to load the plugin

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body));
}
```

Now I thought that adding the ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy would automatically populate error messages on the relevant input field but it doesn't seem to do anything. Instead, whenever I click submit i get 2 errors in the browser console `Unhandled promise rejection > ValidationResult`. Would these be related? Also, Do I need to add in p elements to each input in order for the messages to populate or should it just be done automatically?

EDIT: I have noticed in the browser console, none of the debug messages say the aurelia-validation plugin has been loaded. I navigated to my apps project folder and `jspm install aurelia-validation` and it installed successfully. It is also present in my config.js. It is in jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-validation@0.6.0. It still does not seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug a bit through aurelia-validation source and found out that the only mention of `ValidateCustomAttributeViewStrategy.TWBootstrapAppendToInput` is in [Intro documentation](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/8642558efe83b1ea9d8c5fd6b304905fa52fc995/doc/Intro.md#configuseviewstrategyviewstrategyinstance). This class and their static members seem to be renamed. The new static member you can use instead is `TWBootstrapViewStrategy.AppendToInput`. It can be found in `TWBootstrapViewStrategyBase` [source code](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/src/strategies/twbootstrap-view-strategy.js#L110).

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/pull/153) for that that that should be merged to master branch, however the Intro.md still contains the old config.

P.S. You don't need to add p elements. That will be handled automatically.

P.P.S. You also [need to have](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/163) `.catch` to handle all failed validation when calling `validation.validate()`. That will prevent the error you get in console.

Comment: So, try replacing ValidateCustomAttrbiuteStrategy.TWBootstrapAppendToInput with TWBootstrapViewStrategy.AppendToInput?

Comment: Yes, that should help. Also, you can try removing config from 'aurelia-validation' plugin initialization to use default behavior.

Comment: ah so .plugin((config)...etc yes?

Comment: Still nothing with both of those fixes applied. I'm still not seeing the validation plugin being loaded in the copnsole, but im assuming it must be since clicking submit will throw errors in the console, which could only happen if this.validate.validate() in welcome.js returns invalid

Comment: Not sure. Something else might be the problem... If you are using config, then you also need to `import {TWBootstrapViewStrategy} from 'aurelia-validation';` - take a look at pull request that apparently fixed the documentation, but it doesn't look that Intro.md file is updated - https://github.com/aurelia/validation/pull/153

Comment: Answer updated with the link to https://github.com/aurelia/validation/issues/163 - you should have a `.catch()` after `this.validation.validate()`.

Comment: Yeah I tried pulling that in as well but still nothing. I'm not sure whether this is a code issue or a dependency/npm/jspm type issue

Comment: Yes i have that, I'll update the code, but its a very simple catch, it just logs to console, should I be outputting something here to append to the label?

Comment: Nope, it should be there simply to prevent Aurelia from throwing error in console. I'm using it to display a toast to user that he/she should fix the errors and try again.

Comment: ah ok, well that gets rid of the console errors, but im still not getting the inline message on the input element. I can actually see aurelia-validation in my sources view on Chrome Dev Tools so its definately there. Whether or not its being properly configured is another question

Comment: I tried adding aurelia-validation to default Beta1 skeleton app, using the same configuration as you did above, and everything went smoothly. Are you sure you are using the latest version of aurelia-skeleton-navigation to test this (and hence the latest version of all Aurelia libs)? Try to download the latest from https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/releases and `jspm install aurelia-validation` there.

Comment: Yes, I'm using skeleton-navigation-1.0.0-beta.1.0.1. Im starting to think this may be a configuration issue, possibly with jspm or npm. I'll try it without modifying the skeleton app